# Where do put INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in Model or ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM pattern I have a window which has 3 text boxes namely Name,Address,Description ,a save button and a listview which displays the above fields Name,Address,Description respectively .When the save button is clicked I want to save the fields into database as well as show the record in the listview as well.
Where do I put INotifyPropertyChanged interface Model or in ViewModel or in both place?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged

Comment: One other point to note, if your UI binds to a property on a class, then that class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I don't have a citation to hand for that, hence only a comment).

Comment: @Scroog1, Currently My view has one view model which expose some public properties which I used to bind to the controls on the view so I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged on my ViewModel, and my model contains the same properties but here I dont implement INotifyPropertyChanged is it the right way ?

Comment: Then you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the ViewModel (in general, all ViewModels implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and if you also bind to the Name, Address, etc. properties of the model class (even implicitly) then that neeed to implement it too.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create an additional ViewModel for the Model class and have the list ViewModel expose those to the view instead; but that can get unnecessarily complicated depending on your system design.  That said, I personally prefer not to expose the Model to the View.

Comment: @Scroog1 , then how we access the Model data members in View model by creating an instance of model class in viewmodel?

Comment: The two options are: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Model class (easy); or create another ViewModel to expose the properties of interest from the Model (harder).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, take a look at [the basics of MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) to get a better understanding of how the pattern is supposed to work.  [This WPF specific version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) may be of interest as well.

Generally speaking, the pattern looks like this:

`View` <= (bound) => `ViewModel` <= (function calls + async callbacks) => `Model`

With that diagram in mind, it should be a little more clear that it's the `ViewModel`'s responsibility to notify the `View` when the data has changed.  So the `ViewModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

To further validate that decision, you can see that the `View` should be completely ignorant of the `Model` and it should only know of its `ViewModel`.

In order to simplify implementing `INotifyPropetyChanged`, consider creating a base `ViewModel` class that the other `ViewModel`s inherit from.  That way you only have to write the code once.  [This sample from the MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) has an example `NotifyPropertyChanged()` function that you can use as a reference point.  I believe .NET 4.5 and later allows reflection to be used for the object name instead of relying upon passed strings.

Comment: ,yes I have a doubt,Is we create model class instance in viewModel class the call the model class methods via this instance right?

Comment: @Mussammil - correct.  The VM holds a handle of sort sort (or instantiates a copy) of the Model.  The VM then handles all calls into the Model.  Note that you can have 1 VM : n Models in order to draw together different data sources.  You can also create a hierarchy with the Models with VM facing Models and "private" Models accessed by other Models to draw together multiple sources.  Personally, I think the 1 VM : n Models approach is easier to maintain.

Comment: I have one doubt too, what other than Properties contain in Model class